# In Laravel, create a log to store all changes of resources

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In my Laravel app, which is basically a CRUD application for a number of "resources" (clients, accounts etc), I want to create an audit log. This will enable me to see any creation, deletion or edit of any resource in the app, when it occurred and which user made the change.

I started by creating the following schema (and associated model `Change`):

```
Schema::create('changes', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->dateTime('change_date')->nullable(); //The time the change was made
    $table->string('model'); // The model the change was made to
    $table->text('change'); // What was changed (e.g. `name` field for client 10015 was changed from "John" to "Johnny")
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable(); // The user who made the change
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Now, whenever an change is made to another model I would like my app to insert a record in the changes table. E.g. say a client was edit, some extra code will need to run after the `Client->save()`. Something like:

```
$change = new Change;
$change->user_id = User()->id;
$change->model = // ? how do I get the name of the model just changed?
$change->change = 'User 10015 edited: name: "John" -> "Johnny"; active: 1 -> 0;'; // somehow get the fields that were changed. Different for delete and create.
$change->save();
```

I think I need to make 3 filters (or event listeners?), one each for create, edit and delete. But how do I pass in the required data (like the fields and model name)? Is there a package that already does this? Any help appreciated.

**Edit**
The [revisionable](https://github.com/VentureCraft/revisionable#display) package seems to do 95% of what I want - just doesn't log creates and deletes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34726400/laravel-auditing-eloquent-events-or-alternatives

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34726400/laravel-auditing-eloquent-events-or-alternatives

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener and fire an event.
You can register your event in the `start.php` file or create a `events.php` file and require it in `start.php` file. You can also do it with a service provider and classes.

Example:

```
Event::listen('user.change', function($param1, $param2, $optional = null) {
    // insert a change record here
});
```

and whenever you need to add a change you simply do something like:

```
Event::fire('user.change', ['parameter 1', 'parameter 2']);
```

Obviously you would change the hardcoded parameters to whatever you need.